# How to select previous item in listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, listbox

I have a timer in every tick it adds an item to listbox (or tuple which has two double integer).

For example:

```
20.157
20.158
20.159
20.160
...
```

But I want to separate items to 2 listboxes which has original order and which has ignores first or the last item.

For instance:

```
Listbox1         Listbox2
20.157              -
20.158            20,157
20.159            20.158 
20.160            20,159         
...               ...
```

So how can I seperate items in 2 listboxes as I showed you above?
here is my code;

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTuple2.Add(new Tuple<double,double>
        (Convert.ToSingle(gPathBoylam),Convert.ToSingle(gPathEnlem)));
}

private void pictureBoxPath_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myTuple2.Count-1 ; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(myTuple2[i].Item1);
        listBox2.Items.Add(myTuple2[i-1].Item1);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: If you need to "remember" the previously added item, just store it in a member variable in your code behind and add it to Listbox2 when adding a new value to Listbox1 (and update your variable with the new value).

Comment: You did not show any code, but it seems you are not using the power of **Binding** WPF offers and instead fiddle with controls from your code behind. Don't do this. Learn about Binding and doing things the MVVM way. It may seem difficult at first but take your skills to a new level.